# EE Not Sending Emails to Addresses from Main Domain

Tags: email

Not sure if this is an EE or server issue, but EE will not send any emails to our company addresses, but it will to outside addresses.

For example, our main site is autouplinktech.com. Emails sent from the EE Control Panel on that site arrive just fine in my personal gmail inbox, but no emails can be sent to our company accounts like name@autouplinktech.com.

I have email debugging turned on, but I see no error messages at all, and in fact I get a success message on the CP after sending an email to one of our company addresses, but nothing ever arrives in the inbox.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely a server issue.

You host the site at GoDaddy, but your email is hosted (looking at your MX records) somewhere else. Its likely your server has a local configuration still to handle email for your domain name, maybe a recent switch to another email provider? Your server would listen to the local mail server configuration and deliver locally before it would go off to your outside email company by way of your MX record in DNS.

So make sure your GoDaddy account is not configured to handle email for your domain any more, if you have an outside company handing your email.

Comment: Great answer. I have this problem frequently with my Site5 cpanel hosting and have to remember to set it to not use the local mail server. Also of note, if you're not managing DNS through your hosting account, you may have to duplicate your MX records on the host-- just had this recently.

Comment: @Nevin Yes, it seems to be a server issue, but I still cannot find the exact cause. I added everything from autouplinktech.com to the safe list on both the host server and email server, but still its getting blocked. This issue makes me want to pull my hair out.